# Compare 2 ASCII characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div as follows:

```
<div class="job-article-holder-click-for-more-link">
    &#x25B2;
 </div>
```

and my javascript is as follows:

```
$('.job-article-holder-click-for-more-link').on('click', function () {
    $(this).html() == "&#x25B2;" ? $(this).html('&#x25BC;') : $(this).html('&#x25B2;');
});
```

The check fails every time, how come?  It is basically an arrow, I'm just trying to toggle it to show up and down when I click on it.

Comment: For a start, you've got a lot of white-space to remove before comparing: `$.trim($('this).html()) === "&#x25B2"`, second `html();` may or may not return the character entity-code (the `&#x25B2`) or the character itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than checking the actual HTML, it is probably safer to get the actual character and check it's ascii (well actually unicode) value using [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt). As mentioned, you will need to trim the content first:

```
$('.job-article-holder-click-for-more-link').on('click', function () {
    $(this).text().trim().charCodeAt(0) == 9650 ?
        $(this).html('&#x25BC;') : $(this).html('&#x25B2;');
});
```

Comment: You win, you have posted your answer few seconds prior to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have spaces in what html returns. Try trimming html() output.

```
$('.job-article-holder-click-for-more-link').on('click', function () {
    $(this).html().trim() == "&#x25B2;" ? $(this).html('&#x25BC;') : $(this).html('&#x25B2;');
});
```